# I rm -rf'ed an iSCSI Target

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery, nas

Ok, so yes stupid me, apparently I logged in to my Synology back in January and ran an rm -rf * in my @iSCSI node that housed my VMWare DataStore. Then I rebooted both the ESX and Synology about 3 months later. So because the ESX had a file lock open I was writing to the 'deleted' DataStore for those 3 months and when everything rebooted it all finally deleted when the lock released. I lost ~3TB of data. I have managed to run some recovery tools and have found a deleted ~2TB inode that I can recover. My question is, can/should I recover that inode to another disk and somehow crack it open/map it so I can pull just one or two .vmhd files out of it? Just trying to salvage somethings like my daughter's baby pictures. I have access to Windows and various Linux flavors.

Comment: Always, always, always recover to another disk. don't write anything to the disk you want to recover from.

Comment: Yeah, I have an additional 4TB drive I amusing for the recovery.